# Calling canvas doesn't work

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

Hello I am trying to make a simle canvas

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="java.js">
    </script>

</head>

<body >
    <section id="main">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

java.js :

```
function doFirst(){
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.rect(188, 50, 200, 100);
      context.stroke(); 


}
```

it works if its called by `onload="First()"` in body atribute, but not if its called by 
`window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);` in JS.
Why ?

Comment: Remove the parenthesis from the doFirst argument when you add listener.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean

```
window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);
```

The way you're doing, the `doFirst` function is being called immediatly and its result (`undefined`) is being passed as argument for `addEventListener`.